# i cant enchant the result of the custom crafting recipe

Tags: plugins, minecraft

Hi im trying to make this plugin where when ever someone crafts this custom recipe it will be a piece of paper that has the enchantment LUCK heres a example(without the enchantment):

```
        ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.PAPER, 1);
        
        ShapedRecipe recipe = new ShapedRecipe(item);
        
        recipe.shape("^&^", "%#%", "^%^");
        
        recipe.setIngredient('^', Material.NETHERITE_SCRAP);
        recipe.setIngredient('&', Material.DIAMOND);
        recipe.setIngredient('%', Material.GOLDEN_APPLE);
        recipe.setIngredient('#', Material.NETHERITE_INGOT);
        
        
        
        this.getServer().addRecipe(recipe);
```

this works fine but every time i try to enchant it, the entire crafting recipe doesn't work.
example:

```
ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.PAPER, 1);
        
        ShapedRecipe recipe = new ShapedRecipe(item);
        
        recipe.shape("^&^", "%#%", "^%^");
        
        recipe.setIngredient('^', Material.NETHERITE_SCRAP);
        recipe.setIngredient('&', Material.DIAMOND);
        recipe.setIngredient('%', Material.GOLDEN_APPLE);
        recipe.setIngredient('#', Material.NETHERITE_INGOT);
        
        recipe.getResult().addEnchantment(Enchantment.LUCK, 1);
        
        this.getServer().addRecipe(recipe);
```

Comment: i have found that you need to change the enchantments inside the ItemMeta: https://bukkit.org/threads/enchantments-on-custom-recipe-item-stacks.243106/

Answer (score 1):

Enchant before starting recipe :

```java
ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.PAPER, 1);
ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
meta.addEnchant(Enchantement.LUCK, 1); // add enchant
item.setItemMeta(meta);

ShapedRecipe recipe = new ShapedRecipe(item); // now starting recipe creation

recipe.shape("^&^", "%#%", "^%^");
        
recipe.setIngredient('^', Material.NETHERITE_SCRAP);
recipe.setIngredient('&', Material.DIAMOND);
recipe.setIngredient('%', Material.GOLDEN_APPLE);
recipe.setIngredient('#', Material.NETHERITE_INGOT);

this.getServer().addRecipe(recipe);
```